# Probability game with throwing coin.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Alice and Bob are playing a game. They throw a fair coin, and write out the results of the throws. Each of the players has a victory criterion, the one whose criterion comes first wins. Alice wins at the moment when the results of the last three throws are equal to 001. Bob wins when the results of the last three throws are equal to 010. What is the probability that Alice will win?

Is there any easy way to solve this task? I only see a direct way: finding amount of bit strings with "001" at the end and no substring "010". :(

Comment: See [Penney's Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game)

Answer (score 1):

Let the probability of alice winning = $P$

The possible ways in which alice can win be denoted by $C$.

Then,

$C= (001+0001+00001 \dots \infty) + 011(C) +1(C)$

Here after we have obtained a $011$ configuration ,unlike $010$ where if next one is $0$ Bob will win, the situation kinda resets to initial situation when no coin was tossed and similarily if in the first attempt we land a $1$ the game remains neutral so we can say that the possible cases after $011$ or $1$ are same as initial.

Now for finding the probability we will get a linear eqn and we obtain our answer easily solving it.

$P(0)=\frac12$
$P(1)=\frac12$

$P(C)= (\frac 12.\frac12.\frac12+\frac 12.\frac 12.\frac 12.\frac 12+\frac 12.\frac 12.\frac 12.\frac 12.\frac 12 \dots \infty) + \frac 12.\frac 12.\frac 12.P(C) +\frac 12.P(C)$

$\implies P(C)=\frac 14 + \frac 58.P(C) \implies \frac38.P(C)=\frac14$

$P(C)=\frac23$

I dont think there are any errors in the solution, do confirm the answer

Answer (score 1):

Both sequences contain the subsequence HT, so imagine writing down an infinite number of toss outcomes and scanning for HT subsequences. In order for HTH to occur first, an H must not precede HT (else HHT occurs) and an H must succeed it (to create HTH).

Hence, the probability that HTH wins is $\frac12 \cdot \frac12 = \frac14$ given there is an HT. In order for HHT to occur first, an H must precede HT, which happens with probability $\frac12$ given there is an HT. Note that these are the only two outcomes that can occur and thus define our sample space
$\frac12 + \frac24 = \frac34$.

Finally, Probability that Alice wins = $\frac12 ÷ \frac34 = \frac23$ and the Probability that Bob wins = $\frac14 ÷ \frac34 = \frac13$.

In other words, **HHT is twice as likely to occur before HTH**.

Answer (score 1):

To find Alice's chances of winning, border probabilities $001 =1, 010= 0$

From a starting state s, let useful blocks  (states) be labeled as $0=a,00=b$, and $01= c$
then step by step probability equations for moving from one state to another are

$s = a/2 + s/2 \tag1$
$a = b/2+c/2 \tag 2$
$b= b/2 +1*1/2 \tag 3$
$c= s/2 + 0*1/2 \tag 4$

Solving the set of linear  equations, we get

P(Alice wins) = $\boxed{s= \frac23}$

Comment: Is this somehow connected to Markov's chains?

Comment: @regina: Yes, it is, and this way of solving it is called First Step Analysis

Comment: Thank you for explanation!

Comment: @regina: You're welcome !